# Error in Python's Math library for Haversine function

Tags: python, math, distance, haversine

Im trying to find distance between two geographical lats and longs

Ive created a function haversine with the necessary formula:

```
from math import radians,cos,sin,asin,sqrt
def haversine(lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2):
    #convert decimals to radians
    lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2=map(radians,[lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2])
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r

haversine(-97.481,-97.622,-74.1083,-74.106)
```

Now I want to find the distance the points in my df and if they are within 50km radius of the lat and longs of jersey city:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Company':['WM','WS','WC','WW'],
                   'city':['Norman','OKC','NY','Bayonne'],
                   'latitude':[35.221,35.463,41.112,40.66],
                   'longtitude':[-97.481,-97.622,-74.1083,-74.106]})

jersey_city_lat_lon=(40.94,-74.05)
df['distance']=df.apply(haversine,args=(jersey_city_lat_lon),axis=1)
df[df['distance']<=100]
```

However when I run the above, I receive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-123-8d33df9e0fab>", line 7, in <module>
    df['distance']=df.apply(haversine,args=(jersey_city_lat_lon),axis=1)

  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 6487, in apply
    return op.get_result()

  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 151, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()

  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 257, in apply_standard
    self.apply_series_generator()

  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 286, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)

  File "C:\Users\j\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 78, in f
    return func(x, *args, **kwds)

TypeError: ("haversine() missing 1 required positional argument: 'lat2'", 'occurred at index 0')
```

it should work and show me a location is in New York and the other one is in Bayonne which is within the radius we are looking for since both New York and Bayonne lies within a radial distance of 50 Kms from Jersey City. Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

df.apply passes the row object (or column with axis=0) to the target function. It does not know to unpack the row into the fields that you want. You can wrap your haversign function to extract just the lat and lon columns

```
jersey_city_long_lat=(-74.05,40.94)
def row_hsign(row):
    return haversine(*jersey_city_long_lat,row['longtitude'],row['latitude'])

df['distance']=df.apply(row_hsign,axis=1)
```

Comment: I am looking for an output that is different from what shows up for df['distance']. Please refer this link and let me know what I should change https://kanoki.org/2019/02/14/how-to-find-distance-between-two-points-based-on-latitude-and-longitude-using-python-and-sql/

Comment: oh, looks like because you reverse the order of parameters. haversign's signature is (long1,lat1,long2,lat2) but you specified jersey city by (lat,long). Just switch the order of one or the other to match.

Comment: Still gives same error. I reordered the lat long of jersey city jersey_city_lat_lon=(-74.05,40.94)